# How can I print a specific field from a specific line in a delimited type file

Tags: file, bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a sorted, delimited type file and I want to extract a specific field in specific line.

**This is my input file: `somefile.csv`**

```
efevfe,132143,27092011080210,howdy,hoodie
adfasdfs,14321,27092011081847,howdy,hoodie
gerg,7659876,27092011084604,howdy,hoodie
asdjkfhlsdf,7690876,27092011084688,howdy,hoodie
alfhlskjhdf,6548,27092011092413,howdy,hoodie
gerg,769,27092011092415,howdy,hoodie
badfa,124314,27092011092416,howdy,hoodie
gfevgreg,1213421,27092011155906,howdy,hoodie
```

I want to extract `27092011084688` (value from **4th line**, **3rd column**).

I used `awk 'NR==4'` but it gave me whole 4th line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fairly straightforward:

```
awk -F',' 'NR == 4 { print $3 }' somefile.csv
```

Using `,` as a field separator, take record number 4 and print field 3 in `somefile.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -n "4p" somefile.csv | cut -d, -f3
```

**Edit**

What's this?

- `-n` turns of normal output
- `4p` prints the 4th row
- `-d,` makes `cut` use `,` as delimiter
- `-f3` makes `cut` print the 3rd field

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==4 { print $3 }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==4 {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl` alternative to print element 3 on line 4 in a csv file:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print $F[2] if $. == 4' somefile.csv
```